# I Hope You Like Connect Walls! #3

Tags: word, connect-wall

Here we go again, identifying a Puzzling SE tag from 16 words you would have no idea of any similarity between them. I have made this one harder than the others though.

> ```
>         huge         feline        obese       untruth
>
>        friend        before       succeed      joyful
>
>         wok        policeman     trashcan      insect
>
>       follower       expert       pastry        cork
> ```

And if you know something, please post it as a partial answer.

Comment: Well, I notice a thing that (almost?) all these words have in common, but so far I have been unable to make any plausible groups of 4 using it...

Comment: Well maybe you could post a partial answer to help others chance upon the mythical solution.

Comment: Nah, I have too little to want to post a partial with it. If someone else notices the same thing as me and thinks otherwise, they can have the credit :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think I understand where you are getting at but I also don't see how to continue with that, to make groups of 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EDITED a bit in the light of OP's comments. Might actually be right now.]

The given grid of words

> can be rewritten thus:
>
>  `big cat fat lie`
>  `pal pre win fun`
>  `pan cop bin bug`
>  `fan pro pie cap`

and now

> an obvious thing to do is to find word-ladders (so the missing tag would be `[word-ladder]`) using these words. Here are some that partition our words into four fours:
>
>  `bug big bin win`
>  `pro pre pie lie`
>  `pal pan fan fun`
>  `fat cat cap cop`

Comment: The first two you said were correct. The last two were not.  You also have the right tag in mind. (duh...) and I'm actually surprised you've gotten this far already! Also you have every single synonym correct except gay.

Comment: You have written pig instead of cop. Do, edit that in.

Comment: Well done, this is the intended answer.

Comment: I hoped the solution might have been a word-grid, but +1 anyway!

Comment: @Sid ah yes. Too many alternatives :-). Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:

> untruth, pastry, expert, trashcan: contain a 't' and an 'r' adjacent to each other.
>  feline, obese, before, succeed: two 'e's and one other vowel.
>  huge, friend, joyful, insect: exactly two different vowels.
>  wok, policeman, follower, cork: second letter 'o' and a noun.

And the tag:

> [letters](/questions/tagged/letters)

Comment: Name the tag connected to this.